# Another Lift (Elevator) Simulation Modelling Question

Tags: multithreading, simulation, distributed-computing

I'm playing around with the design of a Lift Simulation. I have a Lift Controller with a collection of Lifts. A Lift moves through particular states (e.g. STATIONARY, MOVING, DOORS_OPEN etc..) - In the MOVING state, the Lift process will simply sleep for X ms. I'm currently focusing on the interactions between the Lift Controller process and the collection of Lift processes.

Essentially, the Lift Controller needs to co-ordinate the Lifts and so needs to take floor requests and determine which Lift is best to service this request and then subsequently inform that Lift.

My initial thoughts were to have each Lift, upon floor request receipt, move itself through the various states, and then inform the Lift Controller once its completed moving to a particular floor. However, with such a design, the Lift Controller may query the lift to see which floor its near, make a decision for that Lift (i.e. stop at next floor), but by the time its told the Lift to stop, that Lift may have moved on past that floor (delay due to say network blip).

To avoid these types of issues (where the Lift Controller makes decisions based on out of date information), I've thought of making the Lift Controller responsible for moving each Lift through its states. With this model, the Lift Controller knows what state a Lift is in, tells it to make a transition, then knows what state it will be in after. As such, the Lift Controller always has upto date information as to what the Lifts are doing, and its actions will never be out of sync with the individual Lift states.

Do people have any concerns with this type of approach (wrt. threading, scalability) - are there better ways of modelling this? Thoughts welcome !

Comment: Why do you want to use multithreading in the first place? Sounds like unnecessary complexity to me, unless you *really* need to performance.

Comment: multithreading as this is the way it would work in practice

Answer (score 1):

The key word on which you based your decision to build more complex lift controller is that some lifts **may** have moved past the state the controller is expecting. I think that the frequency of those "incidents" is low, as is their negative impact on system effectiveness. I would keep it simple, and go with optimistic approach. Expect to have good response from lift, but (if it's really necessary) occasionally deal with the situation when lift is not doing what it's supposed to be doing, and/or pick another lift.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you move all of the control to the lift controller, the synchronization issue will still arise elsewhere.  For instance, if the controller sends a message while a lift is in transit the controller can't know with 100% accuracy what floor the lift will be on when the message is received.

I think your best is to stick with object oriented design best practices and focus on a logical separation of concerns.  ie. Let the lifts worry about lift-related issues and let the controller worry about scheduling.

Commands to lifts can be issued such that lifts acknowledge whether or not they can carry out requested actions. In this scenario you would need to design the scheduling algorithm such that the controller does not to know whether a request will be carried out until a few moments after the request is made - which should be fine if the controller is just doing routing/scheduling.

Of course, this all depends on how realistic you need the simulation to be.

Comment: wrt youf first point, I was thinking of having the Lift inform the Lift Controller of each floor its reached and then only continue until the Lift Controller has acknowledged this. Admittedly, this is additional complexity (adds a little jitter) but the Lift Controller makes decisions with static information.. I do like your points about good OO design - that makes a lot of sense

Comment: @DaveSturgeon Thank you. About having the lift wait for the controller to acknowledge each floor. Is this because you want the controller to always be 'right'?  I agree it is more complex to have the controller correct itself, but this can also lead to interesting solutions... if the controller can be wrong then decisions become probabilistic, and the controller will probably handle new information (ie. someone calls the lift) more gracefully.  You might want to check out [Online Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithms).

Comment: Yes, with the latest information, the Lift Controller should be able to make the best decision. So essentially the Lift Controller is mainly a loop which makes decisions based on requests and current lift state. On each iteration it advances one of the lifts to a new state which should bring the whole system closer to reaching the demands of the current request queue. The Online Algorithms you mention do look quite interesting - thanks for this pointer